# System.Collections.Concurrent already has a dependency defined for System.Runtime

Tags: xamarin, nuget, xamarin-studio

The error can be generalized as this when installing or upgrading a NuGet Package:

> ...already has a dependency defined for...

- Using Xamarin Studio version 6.0.1, build 9 (although this error is not necessarily tied to any Xamarin Studio in particular)
- Attempting to load MvvmCross 4.2.1 (although this error may occur on any number of NuGet package)

**Disclaimer:** *There are a lot of possible answers on SO to similar questions, none of which address the root of this problem*. Questions are framed as a **NuGet Package Manager** version issue, with solutions geared toward updating said **Package Manager**, which is simply not an option with, say, the Mac version of Android Studio.

**Question:** Assuming I am running the latest, stable version of Xamarin Studio, and all I want to do is install a compatible NuGet, what does this error mean and how do I pick a compatible package?

Answer (score 0):

### What does this error mean?

Your version of Xamarin Studio is basically not ready for that `Runtime`. Either wait for an upgrade, tinker with your NuGet Package Manager if you feel so inclined and your environment permits such tweaks, or pick a slightly older NuGet.

### Choose a compatible version of the NuGet Package

Pick the latest version of the NuGet package that is still compatible with your environment. *Using MvvmCross as an example:*

- Specific version
  **Explicitly add `version:x.y.z`**
  `MvvmCross version:4.2.0`
  (4.2.0 happens to be compatible with Xamarin Studio 6.0.1)
- Any version
  **Use unspecified `version:`** (no version following the `:`)
  `MvvmCross version:`
  [image: Search any version using version column]
- Match `packages.config`:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <packages>
     <package id="MvvmCross" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="portable-net45+win+wpa81+MonoTouch10+MonoAndroid10+xamarinmac20+xamarintvos10+xamarinwatchos10+xamarinios10" />
    <package id="MvvmCross.Binding" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="portable-net45+win+wpa81+MonoTouch10+MonoAndroid10+xamarinmac20+xamarintvos10+xamarinwatchos10+xamarinios10" />
    <package id="MvvmCross.Core" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="portable-net45+win+wpa81+MonoTouch10+MonoAndroid10+xamarinmac20+xamarintvos10+xamarinwatchos10+xamarinios10" />
    <package id="MvvmCross.Platform" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="portable-net45+win+wpa81+MonoTouch10+MonoAndroid10+xamarinmac20+xamarintvos10+xamarinwatchos10+xamarinios10" />
  </packages>
  ```

---

### Is Xamarin Studio Up to Date?

Always a good first line of defense:
**Xamarin Studio** > **Check for Updates...** > **Update Chanel:** Stable